# Fb OpenGraph: publish_actions is granted (approved) but my app doesn't list it

Tags: c#, android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Ok so I'm breaking my head in half for trying to figure out what's wrong.

My fb app has been granted the publish_actions permission, I followed up all the [Review Guidelines](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/how-to-submit)

It is also live(public) and with the green circle (meaning it is all ok). [See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDGMD.png)

But... my iOS app (Using Fb Unity SDK) says: "This doesn't let the app post to Facebook" and as of today it doesn't list the permission I have been granted on 09/June/2016

Obviously I can't post anything (mostly photos/videos) from my app...

Here's the code (C#) that I use to init Fb.

```
public void CallFBLogin()
{
    var param = new List<string>(){"public_profile", "email", "user_friends", "publish_actions"};
    FB.LogInWithPublishPermissions(param, AuthCallback);
}

private void AuthCallback(ILoginResult result){
    if(FB.IsLoggedIn){
        //Get Access Token
        var aToken = Facebook.Unity.AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken;
        Debug.Log("ACCESS TOKEN GRANTED");
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("FBAuth", 1);
        //Print current access token's granted permissions
        foreach(string perm in aToken.Permissions){
            Debug.Log("PERMISSION GRANTED: "+perm);
        }
    }else{
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("FBAuth", 0);
        Debug.Log("USER CANCELLED LOGIN");
    }
}
```

Here's the code (C#) that I use to post to Facebook. It works perfectly fine

```
IEnumerator UploadVideoToFB(){

  yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

  //Post to FB Graph API: Video
  //string host = "https://graph-video.facebook.com/v2.6/";
  string uri = "me/videos";
  string videoUrl = mainReviewVideo.m_strFileName;

  String videoUrlIOS = videoUrl.Replace (" ","%20");
  WWW www = new WWW(videoUrlIOS);

  while(!www.isDone){
    yield return null;
    Debug.Log("Progress;" + www.progress);
  }

  //CREATE WWW FORM TO MAKE A POST REQUEST
  var form = new WWWForm();

  //ADD THE VIDEO DATA AS BYTES
  form.AddBinaryData("file", www.bytes, "Video.mov");

  //MAKE THE POST REQUEST, CALLBACK IS UploadVideoFinish
  FB.API(uri, HttpMethod.POST, UploadVideoFinish, form);

}

private void UploadVideoFinish(IGraphResult result){
  var res = JSONNode.Parse(result.ToString());
  string fbVideoID = res["id"];
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I publish something to Fb through my app?

**UPDATE**

So turns out that the workflow for publish_actions is:

1. Login (public_profile, email, user_friends), use:

   ```
   var params = new List<string>(){"public_profile", "email", "user_friends", "publish_actions"};
   FB.LoginWithReadPermissions(params, AuthCallback);
   ```
2. Whenever you are ready to publish something, trigger:

   ```
   var params = new List<string>(){"publish_actions"}
   FB.LoginWithPublishPermissions(params,AuthCallback);
   ```

That way you let your users decide when and who to publish.

Comment: You should never ask for publish permission when the user logs in. Ask for it later when you need it

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, that's my next move. But that didn't answered my question. Also, why would Fb put a method "FB.LogInWithPublishPermissions" If I shouldn't log with Publish Permissions?

Comment: You can't ask for it when the user logs in

Comment: Ok I see... I will give it a try, and come back with the functioning solution. thank you